# xslt more than one insert node if not exists

Tags: xslt

I want to modify my pom.xml in a Maven project. I want to insert two nodes when they don't exists (distributionManagement and profiles). When I start this xslt it inserts only distributionManagement node only, and when I run it once more it inserts profile node.

Here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:m="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" exclude-result-prefixes="m">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"  indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:project[not(m:profiles)]">
    <project>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>dev</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>devel</env>
                    <snapshot>-SNAPSHOT</snapshot>
                </properties>
            </profile>

            <profile>
                <id>prod</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>prod</env>
                    <snapshot></snapshot>
                </properties>
            </profile>
        </profiles>
    </project>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:project[not(m:distributionManagement)]">
    <project>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <distributionManagement>
            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>xxxx.repo</id>
                <name>xxxx Nexus snapshot repository</name>
                <url>http://xxx/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
            <repository>
                <id>xxx.repo</id>
                <name>xxxx Nexus repository</name>
                <url>http://xxx/repository/maven-releases/</url>
            </repository>
        </distributionManagement>
    </project>
</xsl:template>
```

and here is a pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9 to run your XSLT or an XSLT 1 processor (like Xalan or the Xalan version built into the Oracle JRE)? In general, you can in one mode only have one template to be applied to one node, even if you have two templates with the same priority which both match only the last one is used.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes I use javax.xml.transformer.Transformer to converting. Yes I should move it two different xsl, but I think so it needs to work well in one xsl

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to move the code for the new values to parameters and then, at least in XSLT 1, I think you can simply check within the template for `project` with two `xsl:if`s for the two children you are looking for and add them if they don't exist:

```
  <xsl:template match="m:project[not(m:profiles) or not(m:distributionManagement)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
          <xsl:if test="not(m:profiles)">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$new-profiles"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="not(m:distributionManagement)">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$new-dist-man"/>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Full code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:m="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="m"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="new-dist-man">
        <distributionManagement>
            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>xxxx.repo</id>
                <name>xxxx Nexus snapshot repository</name>
                <url>http://xxx/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
            <repository>
                <id>xxx.repo</id>
                <name>xxxx Nexus repository</name>
                <url>http://xxx/repository/maven-releases/</url>
            </repository>
        </distributionManagement>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="new-profiles">
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>dev</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>devel</env>
                    <snapshot>-SNAPSHOT</snapshot>
                </properties>
            </profile>

            <profile>
                <id>prod</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>prod</env>
                    <snapshot></snapshot>
                </properties>
            </profile>
        </profiles>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:project[not(m:profiles) or not(m:distributionManagement)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
          <xsl:if test="not(m:profiles)">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$new-profiles"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="not(m:distributionManagement)">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$new-dist-man"/>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 3 (possible in Java with Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 HE from Maven or Sourceforge) it gets a bit more compact as parameters are normal sequences and we can simply test in a predicate whether the context node not has the appropriate child:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="new-dist-man">
        <distributionManagement>
            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>xxxx.repo</id>
                <name>xxxx Nexus snapshot repository</name>
                <url>http://xxx/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
            <repository>
                <id>xxx.repo</id>
                <name>xxxx Nexus repository</name>
                <url>http://xxx/repository/maven-releases/</url>
            </repository>
        </distributionManagement>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="new-profiles">
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>dev</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>devel</env>
                    <snapshot>-SNAPSHOT</snapshot>
                </properties>
            </profile>

            <profile>
                <id>prod</id>
                <properties>
                    <env>prod</env>
                    <snapshot></snapshot>
                </properties>
            </profile>
        </profiles>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="project[not(profiles) or not(distributionManagement)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), $new-profiles[not(current()/profiles)], $new-dist-man[not(current()/distributionManagement)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8M/